# Outlook API is not returning "Body" parameter when getting messages

Tags: node.js, outlook

I'm building a Node.js application using the Outlook API. I am successfully retrieving a collection response, but each item in the collection only has "Subject" and "From" parameters, but the "Body" parameter is missing. Below is the api request:

```js
outlook.mail.getMessages({token: token, folderId: 'Clutter',  odataParams: queryParams},
      function(error, result){
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error retrieving messages: ' + error);
          response.write("<p>ERROR: " + error + "</p>");
          response.end();
        }
        else if (result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was not including the ("Body") parameter in the ("queryParams") variable that was being passed to the odataParams of the http request.